Why can't the comm command tell the difference between ✓ & ⨯ when LANG=en_US.UTF-8?
If I have two files, a.txt containing:
meow ✓ bar

and b.txt containing:
meow ⨯ bar

Why can't the GNU Coreutils command comm tell the difference between the two when $LANG is set to a UTF-8 encoding?
$ LANG=C comm a.txt b.txt
meow ✓ bar
    meow ⨯ bar

$ LANG=en_US comm a.txt b.txt
meow ✓ bar
    meow ⨯ bar

$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 comm a.txt b.txt
        meow ⨯ bar

Edit: as requested in the comments:
$ od -c a.txt
0000000   m   e   o   w     342 234 223       b   a   r  \n
0000015

$ od -c b.txt
0000000   m   e   o   w     342 250 257       b   a   r  \n
0000015

which doesn't seem to depend on LANG

I suspect an encoding issue. What does od -c say about the file contents?

Maybe both symbols have same lexicological order so "equal"

@j6t Added in the question
